# Sorting map case insensitive

Tags: c++, dictionary

Map implicitly sort elements in it, but is there a way how to force map to sort elements case Insensitive?

using this piece of code

```
map <string , string> m;
m["Axion"] = "second";
m["Beta"] = "third";
m["alpha"] = "first";

for( auto &x : m ){
   cout << x.second << endl;
}
```

it will output    :

```
second
third
first
```

duo to upper case characters having smaller ascii code than lower case characters.

Is there any way how to force map to sort it case inensive so it would output

```
"first"
"second"
"third"
```

Comment: Provide a custom comparer to `map`, or change `std::string` by a `basic_string` with a `char_traits` which does insensitive comparison

Answer (score 0):

The third template parameter to `std::map<>` is a comparison function, just provide it to do a case insensitive comparison...

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map;
```